# Email form data from a webpage

Tags: php, forms, email

I am very new to php and it's been a while since I worked with HTML.  I have several web pages with forms where I would like to email the form data to my email.  I have tried testing with some simple html with the `MAILTO` and this doesn't work.

I am also playing around with a PHP file to email the data and that doesn't work.  Could someone provide some code that really works or direct me to a page that emails form data?  I am seriously frustrated and the hosting service support is useless - they just say the script doesn't work. DUH.  This is what I am testing:
html

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="email_form.php?do=send" method="POST">
    <p>* Required fields</p>
   <?php
   if ($message) echo '<p style="color:red;">'.$message.'</p>';
    ?>
   <table border="0" width="500">
     <tr><td align="right">* First Name: </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="fname" size="30" value="<?php echo @$fname ?>"></td></tr>
     <tr><td align="right">Middle Name: </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="mname" size="30" value="<?php echo @$mname ?>"></td></tr>
     <tr><td align="right">* Last Name: </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="lname" size="30" value="<?php echo @$lname ?>"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <p>

     <TEXTAREA name="fsendmail" ROWS="6" COLS="60"><?php if($fsendmail) echo $fsendmail; ?></TEXTAREA>
     </td></tr>
     <tr><td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Send Now">
     </td></tr>
   </table>
   </form>
    </body>
    </html>
PHP
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>&lt;?php<br>
      switch (@$_GET['do'])<br>
      {<br>
      <br>
    case "send":<br>
    <br>
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];<br>
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];<br>

   $mname = $_POST['mname'];<br>

   if (!preg_match("/\S+/",$fname))<br>
   {<br>
   unset($_GET['do']);<br>
   $message = "First Name required. Please try again.";<br>
   break;<br>
   }<br>
   if (!preg_match("/\S+/",$lname))<br>
   {<br>
   unset($_GET['do']);<br>
   $message = "Last Name required. Please try again.";<br>
   break;<br>
   }<br>

      if ($secretinfo == "")<br>
      {<br>
         $myemail = "jbunns@gmail.com";<br>
         $emess = "First Name: ".$fname."\n";<br>
         $emess.= "Middle Name: ".$mname."\n";<br>
         $emess.= "Last Name: ".$lname."\n";<br>
         
         $ehead = "From: ".$femail."\r\n";<br>
         $subj = "An Email from ".$fname." ".$mname." ".$lname."!";<br>
         $mailsend=mail("$myemail","$subj","$emess","$ehead");<br>
         $message = "Email was sent.";<br>
      }<br>
   <br>
         unset($_GET['do']);<br>
         header("Location: thank_you.html");<br>
       break;<br>
   <br>
   default: break;<br>
   }<br>
    ?&gt;</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Forms don't usually use `mailto` but uses PHP's `mail()` function. In doing so, would defeat the purpose. Do show your code.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that hosting support won't teach you PHP.  It would be rare indeed to find one that does.  As for your code, define "doesn't work."  We don't just provide complete ready-made solutions.  Explain what you tried and how it doesn't work.  We're happy to help answer questions you have about your code, but you need to show that code and ask a question about it.

Comment: Here is a basic form's tutorial http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-form-to-email.html found after Googling "php mail form". Plus, make sure that `mail()` is supported/offered on the server you're using.

Comment: @David I've found that Hosting24 actually provided me with a lot of help with my PHP when I first started using databases! Really impressed with their customer service! That was all before I found this website!

Comment: This is the html I am testing - copied it from a tutorial site:

Comment: @user3713278: 1) There's no HTML in that comment, if you pasted it directly then it was likely removed as part of the formatting. 2) Please put relevant code (formatted appropriately) in the question itself, not in a comment. 3) Where does the process fail? Is the form posting to the PHP code?  Is the PHP code executing?  Is there an error?  Can you debug this and find out where it stops working as expected?

Comment: Also if by any chance you are using free hosting, many of these just don't allow emails to be sent

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

for more info about it, might want to check out http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Tried that Robin and the result is that it displays the php script but does not send email

Comment: You have to start a php script with "<?php" and end with "?>"

Comment: I fixed it and it is now working. I changed the line   header("Location: thank_you.html") to a simple echo line